# Dynamic Programming: Mission Per Day, Scheduling for Maximum Profit

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

**The problem:**

There is a set of n days that Bob is planning to work, and on each day `i` there is a mission; each mission lasts exactly one day, must be done on day `i` in which it is given, and pays bob `x_i` dollars. Bob cannot work more than 5 consecutive missions at a time. That is, he must take at least 1 rest day every 5 days.

`Given` numbers `x_1...x_n`, on which days should Bob perform missions, and on which days should he rest, in order to make as much money as possible and not work more than 5 days? Your solution should be `O(n)`

**My issue:**

I am having trouble coming up with the recurrence for this problem. I have been thinking about this problem for a long time. My original thought was to let `p[i] = max{x_i + x_i-1 + .... + x_i-4}, where p[i] is the max profit earnable from days i-4 to i.` However, I realize, one, that this does take in to account that the optimal solution might have two consecutive work days, and two, I am not building off previous solutions.

**My Question:** Can anyone give me insight on understanding the structure of this problem? I feel like I am just not understanding the key properties that would make the solution easy to see.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really am grateful for all the solutions posted here. I was able to come up with the solution, so I thought I would post it. Note that this solution only returns the maximum profit, not any specific days.

`Let P[i] = the maximum expected profit from day 1...i if Bob rests on day i`

`Recurrence: P[i] = max{p[j] + x_j+1 + x_j+2 + ... + x_i-1, for i - 6 <= j < i` Thus, we want `P[i]` to be the sum of the last five consecutive days that bob would have worked if he rests on day `i`, plus the profit he would have  made by the last rest day `j`

**Code:**

```
def get_best_missions(x):

    n = len(x)

    p = [0 for i in range(n)]

    for i in range(1,n):
        j = i - 6

        if j < 0:
            p[i] = sum(x[0:i])
        else:
            p[i] = max(p[i], p[j] + x[j+1] + x[j+2] + x[j+3] + x[j+4] + x[i - 1])

    return max(p)
```

**Example & Results**

```
x = [10, 10, 10, 5, 20, 10, 5]
best = get_best_missions(x)

p = [0, 10, 20, 30, 35, 55, 55]
best = 55
```

Answer (score 1):

Each day i you have the choice of either working and reducing you remaining work days by 1 and profiting x_i or resting and resetting your available work days to 5, on the base case you are at day 0 with 5 consecutive work days available.

```
if (remaining_rest_days == 0) {
    MaximumProfit(current_day, 0, current_profit) = MaximumProfit(current_day+1, 5, current_profit)
} else {
    MaximumProfit(current_day, remaining_rest_days, current_profit) = 
    max(
        MaximumProfit(current_day+1, remaining_rest_days - 1, current_profits + profit[current_day]),
        MaximumProfit(current_day+1, 5, current_profits)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically build a table of dimensions `6 x n`. The entry `table[w_i][d_j]` will denote the maximal reachable value when Bob has worked for the last `i` days consecutively (including today) and it is day `j`.

The first column is easy to fill in:
`table[1][0] = x_0` if Bob decides to work on the first day, all other values are `0` (`table[0][0]` => Bob doesn't work on the first day, `table[2..5][0]` => Bob can't work for multiple consecutive days on day 1.)

Go on to complete the table column-by-column according to the following rules:

The maximum value on day `j` with `0` consecutive days of work is the maximum of any value of the previous day and not working today:
`table[0][d_j] = max{ table[0..5][d_j-1] }`

The maximum value on day `j` with `1` consecutive day of work is the maximum of the previous 2 days with no consecutive days of work plus `x_j`. (It never makes sense to rest more than 2 days, as we could have just worked the day(s) in between.):

`table[1][d_j] = max{ table[0][d_j-2], table[0][d_j-1] } + x[d_j]`

Otherwise, `table[w_i][d_j] = table[w_i-1][d_j-1] + x[d_j]`.

The solution will be the maximum value in the last column.

Answer (score 1):

I would define the formula as following:

> Let `P(d,i)`:= on day `d`, you have consecutive worked for `i` days(including day `d`), the maximum dollars you can get

With base case `P(1,1) = x_1`, others to 0, 
then the answer is `max(P(n,0), P(n,1)...P(n,5))`

The formula is

```
P(d,0) = max(P(d-1,0), P(d-1,1)...P(d-1,5))
P(d,1) = P(d-1,0) + x_d
P(d,2) = P(d-1,1) + x_d
...
P(d,5) = P(d-1,4) + x_d
```

It obviously can be done with a single loop witch is `O(n)`

My reasoning of the formula is that, for `P(d,i) where i>=1`, it means you work on day `d` and as you consecutive work for `i` days already, the previous `i-1` days you must be working as well, thus the formula `P(d-1, i-1) + x_d`

For `P(d,0)`, it means you rest on day `d`, and you can rest on previous days as well,  but for maximum of 5 days, otherwise it must not be the optimal solution (make sense?), thus the formula `P(d,0) = max(P(d,i)) for i in [0,5]`