# Dynamic Programming - Break Scheduling Problem With Decreasing Work Capacity

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, recurrence

Assume you are given `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, ..., `tn` amount of tasks to finish every day. And once you start working, you can only finish `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, ..., `cn` tasks until spending 1 day resting. You can spend multiple days resting too. But you can only do the tasks which are given you that day. For example;

`T[] = {10, 1, 4, 8}` given tasks;
`C[] = {8, 4, 2, 1}` is the capacity of doing tasks for each day.

For this example, optimal solution is giving a break on the 3rd day. That way you can complete 17 tasks in 4 days:

- 1st day 8 (maximum 10 tasks, but `c1=8`)
- 2nd day 1 (maximum 1 task, `c2=4`)
- 3rd day 0 (rest to reset to `c1`)
- 4th day 8 (maximum 8 tasks, `c1=8`)

Any other schedule would result with fewer tasks getting done.

I'm trying to find the recurrence relation for this dynamic programming problem. Can anyone help me? I find this question but mine is different because of the decreasing work capacity and there are different number of jobs each day. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277713/dynamic-programming-mission-per-day-scheduling-for-maximum-profit)

Comment: I find the problem statement confusing, can you elaborate with several examples what you are trying to solve for? The example you gave, solving for 17 tasks in 4 days does not seem to solve your problem (which has 10+1+4+8=23 tasks in total.) Please spend some time explaining your problem and what you want to compute more clearly.

Comment: Hi @ldog, We can't complete all 23 tasks because we can only complete 8 task the first day of work, 4 tasks 2nd day, 2 tasks 3rd day and 1 task 4th day. Because we get tired. After taking a 1 day break, our capasity to complete tasks is 8 again, then next day it is 4 and so on. Question is, what is the maximum number of tasks that can be completed. **We can only take the tasks which are given to us that day and complete as many of them as we are capable of that day.** Tasks we couldn't complete the day they are given is discarded and can not be completed next day.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you have an amount of tasks to do, `t(i)` for every day `i`. Also you have some kind of a given internal restriction sequence `c(j)` for a current treak day `j` where `j` can be reseted to `0` if no task was done that day. Goal is to maximizie the solved tasks.

Naive approach is to store for each day `i` a list for every state `j` how many tasks were done. Fill the data for the first day. Then for every following day fill the values for the "no break" case - which is
`value(i-1,j-1)+min(t(i),c(j))`. Choose the maximum from the previous day to fill the "break" entry. Repeat until last day. Choose the highest value and trace back the path.

Example for above

[image]

Memory consumtption is pretty easy: `O(number of days * number of states)`.
If you are only interested in the value and not the schedule the memory consumption would be the `O(number of states)`.

Time consumption is a bit more complex, so lets write some pseudo code:

```
For each day i
    For each possible state j
        add and write values
    choose maximum from previous day for break state
choose maximum
For each day
    trace back path
```

The `choose maximum`-function would have a complexity of `O(number of states)`.

This pseudo code results in time consumption `O(number of days * number of states)` as well.